# how to display array values in table smarty php

Tags: php, arrays, smarty

I have array:

```
$kraje = Array(
      array('Polska', 'Anglia', 'Litwa', 'Francja'),
      array('Tunezja', 'Egipt', 'RPA', 'Etiopia'),
      array('Chiny', 'Mongolia', 'Japonia', 'Kazachstan')
);
```

I would like to display this in html table in smarty index.tpl or just in php. the result I want:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LxJpaV

```
<table style="">
  <tr>
    <th>array1</th>
    <th>array2</th> 
    <th>array3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Polska</td>
    <td>Tunezja</td> 
    <td>Chiny</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Anglia</td>
    <td>Egipt</td> 
    <td>Mongolia</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Litwa</td>
    <td>RPA</td> 
    <td>Japonia</td>
  </tr>  
  <tr>
    <td>Francja</td>
    <td>Etiopia</td> 
    <td>Kazachstan</td>
  </tr>   
</table>
```

Comment: Start reading smarty manual.

Comment: or display only in php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`index.php`:

```
require("vendor/autoload.php");
$smarty = new Smarty();

$kraje = Array(
      array('Polska', 'Anglia', 'Litwa', 'Francja'),
      array('Tunezja', 'Egipt', 'RPA', 'Etiopia'),
      array('Chiny', 'Mongolia', 'Japonia', 'Kazachstan')
);
$i = new MultipleIterator();
foreach ($kraje as $a) $i->attachIterator (new ArrayIterator ($a));

$smarty->assign('name', $i);
$smarty->display("sample.tpl");
```

`sample.tpl`:

```
<table style="">
  <tr>
    <th>array1</th>
    <th>array2</th> 
    <th>array3</th>
  </tr>
  {foreach $name as $item}
  <tr>
     {foreach $item as $record}
     <td>{$record}</td>
     {/foreach}
  </tr>
  {/foreach}
</table>
```

Comment: thx @akond but look please one more time the result I expect: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LxJpaV